# Does missing outbound connection flight auto cancel inbound flight?

Tags: air-travel, connecting-flights

Because of a delay in the first outbound flight, we missed the connection flight.
The airline company compensated us by providing a bus to our final destination.

When trying to check in to our inbound flight, we got an error and when calling the airline company they said that our flight was cancelled because we didn't made the connection flight.
Is that a normal procedure?

**It gets worse**

After some talking on the phone, they booked us the connection flight and "couldn't guarantee" about the final flight.

When we arrived at the airport the flight was fully booked and we (16 people with babies) needed to stay for the next flight.

Do we have a case here?

Comment: What country were you flying from/to?

Comment: From Israel to Austria and vice versa

Comment: Which airline(s)?

Comment: @Willeke, how is that related?

Comment: @ReaKrakover Because it might affect any compensation rights and because it will enable anyone wishing to answer to research the specific airline policy (presumably you did this already before posting your question)

Comment: @Willeke, it's Austrian Airlines. I've already checked the policy regrading overbooking. my main question is regarding the fact that they automatically cancelled our inbound flight

Comment: It sounds like you might have been flagged as a no-show for the second leg of your outbound flight. Airlines will frequently cancel the remainder of your itinerary if a traveler intentionally skips a leg. But since you missed the second leg because of airline delays, that policy shouldn't have applied here.

Comment: It might also be relevant if all your flights were on one ticket purchased from one source, and that you had only one PNR (Passenger Name Record) for all the flights. The PNR is the six-letter "locator" assigned by the airline to your flights. Did you have a single PNR, or several PNRs?

Answer (score 2):

> Does missing outbound connection flight auto cancel inbound flight?

That depends on what exactly happened during the outbound flight. If you missed the connection due to the airline's fault, they should NOT have cancelled your return flight.

> The airline company compensated us by providing a bus to our final destination.

Did they actually organize and paid for the bus or did you book the bus tickets by yourself and just had the airline compensate you for the expense?  Either way, if you have some proof that the airline paid for the bus, you have evidence that this was the airline's fault, that they knew exactly what was happening and that you were NOT a now show.

This sounds very much like they cancelled your return trip in error.

> Do we have a case here?

I believe so. As long as you can proof that the missed connection was the airline's fault and they knew about it they are indeed at fault here.  The question is, of course, what to do with that. You can reach out, show your evidence and ask for compensation.

Comment: Thanks! The bus was organized by the airline and the delay was because of the airline company. We'll gather all the information to demand a compensation. Thanks again

Comment: Then you gave a really strong case. If the airline organized a bus for you, they can't claim that you were a no show